# Recursively traverse tree in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

This is super simple task to do in Java but the asynchronous nature of javascript makes this task(for me) almost impossible, at least with my knowledge now.(I'm not trying to bash javascript.  Love the language!).

It's very basic.  A top level tree has a parent of null in my mysql database.  It's easy finding children.  The children have lines available to them.  The depth of the tree is variable.

```
    private static Set<Tree> getBranches( Tree trunk ) {

    Set<Tree> treeSet = new HashSet<Tree>();

    if ( trunk != null ) {

        if ( trunk.hasLines() ) { //queries if tree has lines.  returns true or false
            treeSet.add( trunk );
        }

        for ( Tree tree : trunk.treeList ) {
            treeSet.addAll( getBranches( tree ) );
        }
    }

    return treeSet;
}
```

Basically the method tests if the tree has lines available.  If it does it adds all of those to a set.  If not it continues until it finds lines.

The asynchronous nature of the mysql node library turns this task into hell.

Here is what I have now

```
   function hasLines(tree_id, callback) {
        var ret;
        pool.query('SELECT * from pkg_line_tree where tree_id = ?', [tree_id], function (err, rows) {

            if (rows.length > 0) {
                ret = true;
            } else {
                ret = false;
            }
            callback(ret);
        });
    }


     function dig(tree_id, treeArray, callback) {

        pool.query('SELECT * from tree where parent_id = ?', [tree_id], function (err, rows) {

           if (rows) {

              for (var i in rows) {
                 hasLines(rows[i].tree_id, function (t) {

                    if (t) {
                       treeArray.push(rows[i].tree_id);
                    } else {
                       treeArray.concat(dig(rows[i].tree_id, treeArray));
                    }
                 });
              }

              if (callback) {
                 callback(treeArray);
              }

           }
        });

        return treeArray;
     }


     var treeArray = [];
     dig(52, treeArray, function (t) {
        res.json(t);
     });
```

I really just need to output all the children available in this root tree.

Please let me know if this doesn't make sense.  I'll try to refactor.  I'm hoping I got some kind of point across.  I'd hate to use something like Fibers to get this done but I'm out of options.  Thanks.

Comment: So is your question how to maintain the original tree order in the output when perusing the tree asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `dig()` isn't currently consistent:

```
// asynchronous with callback
dig(52, treeArray, function (t) {
   res.json(t);
});

// then synchronous with `return`?
treeArray.concat(dig(rows[i].tree_id, treeArray));
```

Also, the `concat` in the last line isn't actually doing much, since it doesn't alter the array it's called on. You probably wouldn't actually want it to as `dig` passes around the `treeArray` rather than defining a new `treeSet` like in `getBranches`. So, if it did, it would append `treeArray` onto the end of itself each time.

You could still use `concat` with multiple `treeSet`s, but you'd have to store its `return` value:

```
treeSet = treeSet.concat(subSet);
```

And, you'll have to replace the `for` loop this with an asynchronous iterator as the loop won't wait for asynchronous operations before continuing. The [`async` library](https://npmjs.org/package/async) has a few options for this, if you're up for trying it.

So, with multiple `treeSet`s, `concat`, and [`async.forEachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEach), you could try:

```
function dig(tree_id, callback) {
  var treeSet = [];

  hasLines(tree_id, function (yep) {
    if (yep) {
      treeSet.push(tree_id);
    }

    pool.query('SELECT * from tree where parent_id = ?', [tree_id], function (err, rows) {

      function each(row, next) {
        dig(row.tree_id, function (subSet) {
          treeSet = treeSet.concat(subSet);
          next(null);
        });
      }

      function done() {
        callback(treeSet);
      }

      async.forEachSeries(rows, each, done);
    });
  });
}

dig(52, function (treeSet) {
  res.json(treeSet);
});
```

Comment: Wow guys this is great.  I'm not sure which one to mark as answer at this point.  I'm leaning towards this answer though cause it's more simple and concise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you have to use async https://github.com/caolan/async

I have modified your dig function to use async's forEach method

```
function dig(tree_id, treeArray, AllDone) {
       pool.query('SELECT * from tree where parent_id = ?', [tree_id], function (err, rows) {
          if (rows) {
            async.forEach(
                rows,
                function(row, callback) {
                    hasLine(row.tree_id, function(t){
                        if (t) {
                            treeArray.push(row.tree_id);
                            callback();
                        }
                        else {
                            dig(row.tree_id, treeArray, callback);
                        }
                    });
                },
                function(err) {
                    if (err) AllDone(err, treeArray);
                    else AllDone(null, treeArray);
                });
            }
          else 
            AllDone(null, treeArray)
        });
}

treeArray = [];
dig(52, treeArray, function(err, t) {  
    res.json(t);  
});
```

assuming rows is an array.. `forEach` go through each row and perform hasLine, each iteration will call the `callback` function when it finish, and `AllDone` will be called when all `callback` functions are called. the tricky part here is the recursion, each recursive call will have a `forEach` loop, and it will call the `AllDone` method only when all `callbacks` are finish.

however `forEach` execute in parallel, so order is not perserved

I think this should work, if you don't care about order.

**Edit** : **you can use `forEachSeries` to solve the order problem.**

Comment: That's the question I've asked; it's a completely different problem if he does care about order.

Comment: I guess use forEachSeries instead of forEach like in Jonathan's answer

Comment: Wow guys this is great.  I'm not sure which one to mark as answer at this point.  Thanks for your help.